# Angularjs not working and page loading too slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going through a tutorial on w3schools and I copied one of their snippets. When I try to view the page in my browser it takes like half a minute to load. Also, the functions simply aren't working. This code seems to work only on w3schools. They've provided cdn's (which are outdated but should still work). Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/">Main</a></p>

<a href="#banana">Banana</a>
<a href="#tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>The HTML shown in the ng-view directive are written in the template property of the $routeProvider.when method.</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "<h1>Main</h1><p>Click on the links to change this content</p>"
    })
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a side note I would suggest you to follow the official angular website. They've got a great tutorial.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. :)

Comment: `ngRoute` script inclusion is missing https:

Comment: Just download js files and insert them locally.

Answer (score 1):

Loading time may due to your network connection, as the page needs to download the angular core from google CDN. Load it locally may solve it.

However, I noticed you have such code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

So I'm wondering, how are you visiting your HTML? Do you have a localhost server or directly via `file:///` protocol?

If your answer is latter, then it definitely won't work, as the URL for angular-router may be auto-prefixed as via `file:///` protocol too, which is 404 I guess.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been visiting my html by the file protocol. I'm glad that you explained that part for me. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: @thetekkenmaster Then you need to learn setting up a dev server on localhost. It is also required if you want to develop something AJAX.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. I figured out how to view it on localhost. I downloaded xampp. Everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The angular route file you have used is not valid. Please use a valid cdn URL

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```